# how to delete/subtract/remove one data frame completely from another one on Pyspark and export to csv

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know there is a couple of question regarding a similar topic, I reviewed and tried them all. still getting error/not working. so I posted this question for more solutions.

I have two datasets (all data are made by me, not really data):

```
df 1:
ID    week_id  month_id  school cd class code
1     20200103  202001       A        103
1     20200110  202001       A        105
1     20200103  202001       B        202
2     20200103  202001       B        205
2     20200103  202001       C        202



df 2:
ID    week_id  month_id  school cd class code
1     20200103  202001       A        103
2     20200103  202001       C        202

The output I want is df1 - df2
ID    week_id  month_id  school cd class code
1     20200110  202001       A        105
1     20200103  202001       B        202
2     20200103  202001       B        205

I used a couple methods:
1. df1.substrac(df2) 
2. also use left anti with df1.ID = d2.ID and df1.school_cd != df2.school_cd
3. also use spark.sql with not in
```

maybe because both data are really big, after I did the subtract, then I need to do a weekly ID count, so I used to group by and gag(count distinct), then I need to export the count into CSV file. and that is the part that error occurs. I am new to spark and not really understand the error quiet sure, I googled it and try to increase the memory and maxResultSize. but still getting errors:

I also wonder if there is any quicker or easier to see the counts, usually the code run through really fast, but when I want to see the count, and running .show(), that will take forever, and usually end up with job failed with red error pop up.

Here is a copy of the error: I don't know if that will help or not.

I am still new to spark, any advice will really be appreciated! Thank you!

```
Jan20200103_cnt.toPandas().to_csv("wk_cnt_20200103.csv")

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2250.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(school_cd#5854, week_id#3610, 200)
+- *(21) HashAggregate(keys=[school_cd#5854, week_id#3610], functions=[partial_count(distinct id#3614L)], output=[school_cd#5854, week_id#3610, count#16086L])
   +- *(21) HashAggregate(keys=[school_cd#5854, week_id#3610, id#3614L], functions=[], output=[school_cd#5854, week_id#3610, id#3614L])
      +- *(21) HashAggregate(keys=[school_cd#5854, week_id#3610, id#3614L], functions=[], output=[school_cd#5854, week_id#3610, id#3614L])
```

Comment: This is the left anti code I used: df1.join(df2,
    [df1.id == df2.id,df1.school_cd == df2.school_cd,df1.class_cd = df2.class_cd], 
    how='left_anti'
)

Comment: `df1.subtract(df2)` gives me your intedend output?

Comment: The conversion of toPandas() is collecting the data to driver node and since data is large, it is failing. Instead of writing to a single file, try to save the file using spark.write() method. Note: This will give you partitioned files i.e multiple csv files will be present. If u want the entire data frame to be saved to single file, divide the original dataframe to smaller dataframes which will fit in memory, convert them toPandas() and keep appending those dataframes to the file you want.